# JavaCV findContours outlining the image instead of finding the contour

Tags: opencv, image-processing, javacv

I am trying to find that whether there is any rectangle/square present inside my area of interest. Here is what I have achieved till now.

Below is the region of interest which I snipped out of the original image using JavaCV.

```
        Mat areaOfInterest = OpenCVUtils.getRegionOfInterest("image.jpg",295,200,23,25);

 public static Mat getRegionOfInterest(String filePath , int x, int y, int width, int height){

    Mat roi = null;

    try{
        Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(filePath);
        Rect region_of_interest= new Rect(x,y,width,height);
        roi = image.submat(region_of_interest);

    }catch (Exception ex){

    }
    return roi;
}
```

[image: Region of interest]

Now I'm trying to find whether there is any rectangle present in the area of interest. I have used following lines of code to detect that as well.

```
    Mat gray = new Mat();
    Mat binary = new Mat();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    ArrayList<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    cvtColor(image,gray,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Core.bitwise_not(gray,binary);
    findContours(binary,contours,hierarchy,RETR_EXTERNAL,CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    if(contours.size() > 0){
        for (MatOfPoint contour:contours) {
          Rect rect = boundingRect(contour);
          /// x = 0, y = 1 , w = 2, h =3
          Point p1 = new Point(rect.x,rect.y);
          Point p2 = new Point(rect.width + rect.x, rect.height+rect.y);
          rectangle(image,p1,p2,new Scalar(0,0,255));
          Imgcodecs.imwrite("F:\\rect.png",image);
        }
    }
```

But instead of finding the the square inside the image it is outlining the parts of the image as following.
[image]

It would be great if someone pushes me in the right direction.

Comment: `bitwise_not` will not turn your gray image binary. If you have a grayscale value, say 100, that is `01100100` in binary. If you `bitwise_not` that value, you'll get `10011011`. `bitwise_not` only makes sense to flip a binary image in most cases, e.g. the grayscale values are all zeros in binary or all ones in binary. Simple solution is just to use `threshold()` or `inRange()` to binarize your image, *then* you can invert it and the rest of your code should work :)

Comment: To be clear, the reason this doesn't work is because your image is a `jpg`, the whites aren't exactly perfectly white---so when you invert, they're not perfectly black either. `findContours()` will treat the incoming image as binary by pixels = 0 and pixels != 0. The black on your inverted image is probably like 3 or 8 or whatever instead of 0. If you threshold at a middle gray value (like 127), you can set every pixel above 127 to 255 and every pixel below to 0 so you have a truly binary image.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Thanks for the answer. It started working after I added the line `Imgproc.threshold(gray,binary,127,255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV)`
But Still I hav one doubt that, When the above line is changed to 
`Imgproc.threshold(gray,binary,127,255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);`
it stops working. Is it that, OpenCV is looking for contours which are outlined in white color?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Got it from OpenCV website : In OpenCV, finding contours is like finding white object from black background. So remember, object to be found should be white and background should be black.
Thanks.

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer---wasn't sure if it was the only thing wrong as I don't have OpenCV compiled for java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV's `findContours()` treats the input image as binary, where everything that is 0 is black, and any pixel >0 is white. Since you're reading a `jpg` image, the compression makes it so that most white pixels aren't exactly white, and most black pixels aren't exactly black. Thus, if you have an input image like:

```
3 4 252 250 3 1
3 3 247 250 3 2
3 2 250 250 2 2
4 4 252 250 3 1
3 3 247 250 3 2
3 2 250 250 2 2
```

then `findContours()` will just outline the whole thing, since to it it's equivalent to all being 255 (they're all > 0).

All you need to do is binarize the image with something like `threshold()` or `inRange()`, so that your image actually comes out to

```
0 0 255 255 0 0
0 0 255 255 0 0
0 0 255 255 0 0
0 0 255 255 0 0
0 0 255 255 0 0
0 0 255 255 0 0
```

Then you'd correctly get the outline of the 255 block in the center.